# extract number from string in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the below format and and trying to use the extract function but I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

```
column1    column2
1         abc2150/abc2152/abc2154/abc215601/U215602


df.column2.str
    .split('/',expand=True)
    .apply(lambda row: row.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=True))
    .apply(lambda x: '/'.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

I need the output in the below format.

```
column1    column2
1         2150/2152/2154/215601/215602
```

Please let me know how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead use [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with a positive lookahead to remove all characters that precede the numerical part:

```
df.column2.str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]+(?=\d+)','')

 0    2150/2152/2154/215601/215602
Name: column2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
df['column2']=df.column2.str.replace('abc','')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I will do:

```
df.loc[:, "column2"] = df.column2.apply(lambda x: re.sub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", x))
```

Comment: could the down -voter please explain what was wrong with the solution?

Comment: Maybe you mixed the slice methods? `df["column2"] = df["column2"].apply(lambda x: re.sub("[a-zA-Z]+", "", x))` will not get downvotes?